# JavaScript Calculator always rounding to floor

Tags: javascript

I have made a calculator of my need but it's rounding to floor all my results.

How can I make it to show exact results?

```
function toFixed(value, precision) {
var precision = precision || 0,
  neg = value < 0,
  power = Math.pow(10, precision),
  value = Math.round(value * power),
  integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
  fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
  padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');
     return precision ? integral + '.' +
  padding + fraction : integral; } function dosage () {

  var a =  parseInt(jQuery("#a").val() ) ;
  var b =  parseInt(jQuery("#b").val() ) ;
  var c =  parseInt(jQuery("#c").val() ) ;
  var r = Math.round(a*((a*(b/100)*2)+(c*25.4))*(0.0152/100));
 r = toFixed(r,1);
```

Comment: Can you give the values for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wrote the code, then you added:

```
 integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power))
```

So, if you don't want `Math.floor`, you should take it out?
Or, if sometimes you want `Math.floor`, you need to investigate the `neg` value as this is what is causing your return value to always be rounded down.

The line, as you have it seems incorrect as the second part:

```
 (value / power)
```

Is just an expression that is next to the result of your ternary operation. I'm not sure how that portion is affecting anything.

Comment: the OP says "it's rounding to froor all my results." - I think the emphasys is on **all** here...

Comment: But, the OP also says "How can i make it to apear exact result."

Comment: hey Scott, it's me again, we chatted yesterday, remember? ;) I like your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code for testing

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
function dosage_e(e)
 {
e.preventDefault();
dosage();
}

function toFixed(value, precision) {
var precision = precision || 0,
  neg = value < 0,
  power = Math.pow(10, precision),
  value = Math.round(value * power),
  integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
  fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
  padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');
     return precision ? integral + '.' + padding + fraction : integral; } 

function dosage () {      
      var a =  parseInt(jQuery("#a").val() ) ;
      var b =  parseInt(jQuery("#b").val() ) ;
      var c =  parseInt(jQuery("#c").val() ) ;
      var r = Math.round(a*((a*(b/100)*2)+(c*25.4))*(0.0152/100));
     r = toFixed(r,1);

jQuery("#result").val(r);}


jQuery("#a").keyup(
   function (e) { dosage(e); } );

jQuery("#b").keyup(
   function (e) { dosage(e); } );

jQuery("#c").keyup(
   function (e) { dosage(e); } );

   dosage(); } ); // ]]&gt;

</script>


 <div id="fond-voiture" align="center">

  <div><h1 style="color:white; font-family:Arial;">VALUE 1</h1><input id="a" type="text" name="a" value="385" />
  </div>
</br>
  <div><h1 style="color:white; font-family:Arial;">VALUE 2</h1><input id="b" type="text" name="b" value="65" />    
  </div>
</br>
  <div><h1 style="color:white; font-family:Arial;">VALUE 3</h1><input id="c" type="text" name="c" value="22.5"/>
  </div>
</br>
  <div><h1 style="color:white; font-family:Arial;">VALUE 4</h1><input id="result" readonly="readonly"/>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```